# Passing a Closure as a method argument in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, arguments, closures

I'm writing a service in Grails 3.

Let's say I wrote a method like this for a 'PostsService'

By default it should sort the categories by their id.

```java
List<Category> getCategories(List<Post> posts) {
    List<Category> categories = ... // logic to get categories
    categories.sort { it.id }
    return categories
}
```

What if I wanted to add flexibility for sorting. For example, later we want to sort by year instead.

I want to add the sort Closure as an optional argument.
I tried this.

```java
List<Category> getCategories(List<Post> posts, Closure sortClosure = null) {
    List<Category> categories = ... // logic to get categories
    if (sortClosure == null) {
        categories.sort { it.id }
    } else {
        // Trying to use the sortClosure. Not sure if these will work.
        // sortClosure << categories.sort
        // categories.sort sortClosure
    }
    return categories
}
```

I try to run the method with the Closure

```java
List<Category> categories = postsService.getCategories(posts, { it.year })
```

But I'm running into errors. It throws an internal server error at this line.

```java
List<Category> categories = postsService.getCategories(posts, { it.year })
```

> **Class** java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

> **Message** null

> **Caused by** PostsController$_select_closure5: method (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V not found

What am I doing wrong here? Can I use a Closure this way?

[One of the resources I've been looking at](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/groovy-closure-example/)

Comment: Is it safe to assume, that you don't get above error, if you run the code like above (with your sort-logic commented out)? Also whenever I see this class of error `(L...)V` I restart the application because hot-reloading of the code has failed. Can you rule that out?

Comment: @cfrick Good idea removing the other logic! You were right about the hot reloading failing though. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as correct and edit my question to make it more useful for others.